# SlimDX and WPF (DirectX 11)

Tags: c#, wpf, slimdx, directx-11

I want to use SlimDX (DirectX 11) to render the contents of an Image in WPF.

The problem is that I can't find a way to link the SwapChain to a D3DImage. (The DirectX 11 example uses the SlimDX RenderForm.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the WPF example in the DX10 examples.  It should work about the same for DX11 I think.  Because the D3DImage only works with DX9 stuff, you need to use a dx10/11 shared texture.

Comment: This answers about half of my question: DX11 is quite different from DX10 and uses a SwapChain for rendering. What I need help with is how to render from the SwapChain into a Texture2D.

Comment: Actually DX11 isn't that different to 10, read the "upgrading to DX11" document on MSDN. It's a fraction of the effort of upgrading from DX9 to 10 or 11. As for the DX10 WPF example in the SlimDX SDK, I am having a lot of trouble getting this to run on some hardware/OS configs. It seems particularly failure-prone on Vista64.

Answer (score 4):

Direct3D 10 and 11 are not too different in API or how they work.  A SwapChain is used to present to an hWnd, not required to render.  This is the same with DX10, and even the very different DX9.

In any case, this example I made should be enough to help you take your Texture2D that you render to and pass it to WPF.  Don't remember if I finished the DX11, but it's pretty much the same thing.
http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/437/Direct3D-10-11-Direct2D-in-WPF.aspx

Comment: I wasn't sure how to create a new texture and use it as render target, but thanks to your answer I finally know what I was doing wrong. You're not using managed code for the `D3DImageEx` though, so I'm accepting mdm20's answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go take a look a Jeremiah Morill's [DirectCanvas](http://directcanvas.codeplex.com/) implementation on Codeplex. He is also very helpful if you drop him a line.

Comment: This is interesting as a resource for examples, but doesn't answer my question as I want to use DirectX 11.